# "What do we do?" usage

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning

If one means *next*, as if *waiting for orders or instructions*, is it possible to use the expression **what do we do?**  Or should we say *what are we going to do?*

Is there a reason to prefer one over the other? Is there a better way to use *next* as in *waiting for instructions*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely say things like, "Okay, what do we do now?" and a shortened but still valid version of that would be, "What do we do?"